# Unable to resolve service registered via assembly scanning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, scrutor

**Configuration**

I have :

- A .net core MVC app project
- A module project containing

  - A controller (MyController),
  - A repository interface (IMyRepository)
  - A repository (MyRepository which Implements IMyRepository and IRepository)

The .net core app references the module project

I have used Scrutor in the MVC app to grab all classes that implement `IRepositoy` in any referenced projects and register them in the services collection:

```
public static void RegisterAllTypes<T>(this IServiceCollection services, ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped)
{

    var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    var referencedAssemblies = entryAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(Assembly.Load);
    var assemblies = new List<Assembly> { entryAssembly }.Concat(referencedAssemblies).ToArray();

    services.Scan(
        x =>
        {
            x.FromAssemblies(assemblies)
                .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo(typeof(T)))
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()

                .WithLifetime(lifetime);
    });
}
```

**The Problem**

If I examine the services collection I can see that *IMyRepository* is registered and should resolve to *MyRepository*. However, the repository when injected into *MyController* as per below:

```
private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository ;

public MyController(IMyRepository myRepository )
{
    _myRepository = myRepository;
}
```

throws the error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'IMyRepository' while
>   attempting to activate
>   'MyController.

Unless...

After registering the repositories via Scrutor I put

```
var test = typeof(IMyRepository);
```

At which point everything works as expected. But that defeats the entire point of automatic dependency registration.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please also share the code in Startup class where this register method is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed registration method to use **FromApplicationDependencies()** and now everything seems to be ok.

```
public static void RegisterAllTypes<T>(this IServiceCollection services, ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped)
{
    services.Scan(
        x =>
        {
            x.FromApplicationDependencies()
                .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo(typeof(T)))
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .WithLifetime(lifetime);
        });
}
```